# ASPxGridView PerformCallback() does full page postback

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, data-binding

I have a checkbox that when clicked, calls a javascript program that calls grid.PerformCallback(), where grid is the client instance name of my ASPxGridView gridview. This gridview also has a custom callback method which databinds the table. However when i click my checkbox, instead of only performing callback on the gridview, my page does a full postback, which posts the form. How do i make it so that it only updates the gridview?

```
 function toggle()
    {                         
        productGrid.PerformCallback();
    }//end toggleExch()

<dx:ASPxGridView ClientInstanceName="productGrid" Width="100%" ID="productGrid" runat="server"
                DataSourceID="ProductSQL" EnableCallBacks="true" OnCustomCallback="productGrid_OnCustomCallback">            
        </dx:ASPxGridView>

protected void productGrid_OnCustomCallback(object sender,
                        DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewCustomCallbackEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("in postback");
    productGrid.DataBind();
}//end productGrid_OnCustomCallback()
```

so basically the debug line is not printed and the page goes into full postback - how do i only postback and databind the grid? (i need to do more server side processing before databinding or directly binding from jquery is out of the question)

Comment: sorry for the confusion - i meant when i click my checkbox, it calls a javascript function which calls the postback for the grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer - should use iscallback instead of ispostback

Comment: For information to any to whom it may concern: Every callback is also a postback. Callback is a special kind of postback.

Comment: where to  use iscallback instead of is postback?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you did not post the aspx markup of the button.  However, if this is the ASPxButton, make certain that its AutoPostback property is false ...

Comment: found the answer - should use iscallback instead of ispostback